# Strip NSString of special characters in setter method in implementation file in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, setter

I have a property

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *myString;
```

where I store an NSString and this property is called in many places in the implementation file as self.myString.

I have run into a problem where the string sometimes contains an angled apostrophe as opposed to the kind on the QWERTY keyboard and this special character is throwing off string comparisons.

With a managed object, you can use the setter method to do things to a property.  Is there a way that I can use a setter method to convert the angled apostrophe into a regular apostrophe in an implementation file.

Something like:

```
-(NSString*) myString {
    NSString * myString = [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"’" withString:@"'"];
}
```

This is a mixed Objc-Swift project, so I guess I could also add an extension to NSString in Swift if that is a better way to do it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As setter:

```
- (void)setMyString:(NSString *)aString {

    _myString=[aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"’" withString:@"'"];
}
```

However you could also leave it a regular property, storing it exactly as received, but providing a derived property that would sanitize the string. Example:

```
- (NSString *)myStringSanitized {

    return [self.myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"’" withString:@"'"];
}
```

Optionally if your code uses Key-Value observation (for example with Cocoa Bindings), you could also add this to make sure a change notification for your sanitized string is fired whenever the underlying original changes:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingMyStringSanitized {

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"myString",nil];
}
```

Now you can use `self.myStringSanitized` anywhere you need the sanitized version of your string, but you still have the unmodified version available as `self.myString`.